# Sending image between two Qt exe

Tags: c++, qt, exe

I'm trying to make my applications able to send images to each other without saving it.

I've found there's several ways to achieve the goal. Including:

QSharedMemory

QLocalServer

QProcess

I would like to use QSharedMemory but I don't know how to send a signal from one to another to make a request. The following example shows how to use QShareMemory but no sending signal.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc-sharedmemory.html

If I choose to sue QLocalServer, that means I have to communicate through network(?). I don't know if this is a good idea or not cause image files can be huge.

If I choose to use QProcess, I don't know how to make a connection between two apps if they are open separately by directly double click the exe.

Any suggestions? Thanks very much!

**Update**

I try to use QLocalSocket but I'm stuck sending image to another application cause stuck in the bytesAvailable() while loop.

```
QByteArray block;
QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3);
if(client_status == 0)
{
    out << m_message;
}
else if(client_status == 1)
{
    out << m_image;
}
out.device()->seek(0);
m_socket->write(block);
m_socket->flush();
```

The program stucks here.

`while (clientConnection->bytesAvailable() < (int)dataSize)`

I try to set the size of the `dataSize` equal to `block.size()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I would like to use QSharedMemory*

Why do you have a desire to do this?

If the applications are on the same machine, then I suggest using QLocalServer. Functionally it may appear to require a network, as the concepts are similar to QTcpSocket, but in reality, no network is required. As the docs state for [QLocalSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocalsocket.html#details)

> *On Windows this is a named pipe and on Unix this is a local domain socket.*

If applications are running on different machines, then I suggest using QTcpServer, which has a similar functional interface as QLocalServer and QLocalSocket.

[QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html) is not the solution here. Whilst the docs state "*The QProcess class is used to start external programs and to communicate with them*" the communication is referring to controlling the application, sending input and receiving its output and error streams.

Comment: Thanks! But who will be the server? If the server is not opened, can I request Qt to open it for me?

Comment: Either can be the server. It depends on your design. Note that you can get the path to the file with QLocalServer::fullServerName and check for the existence of it with QFileInfo::exists.

Comment: Thanks for giving me wonderful ideas. I achieve my goal by using QSharedMemory + QLocalSocket